# Facebook for Android FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder doesn't recognize URI returned by Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am relatively new to android and facebook so please bear with me.  IMPORTANT NOTE: Wherever I type h.. that means http://www.   I'm not intending to post links here but I have to in order to explain this (my permission only allows 2 links) so please bear with me.

This app does a facebook post using the FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder.  This all works great now IF the image for the post using the .setPicture method is given a static hardcoded URL h..example.com/share_name/image_name.png.  In that case the post works and the picture shows up on the post and everything is fine.

However, the image sent to the post is dynamically created by the app.  Therefore I am sending the image to facebook's staging area which also works fine. 
The Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest returns a response that has the JSON encoded URI of the location of
the image in facebook's staging area.

The problem is that the FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder doesn't like that URI location.  Somehow it's not formed properly or something or I'm just doing something wrong.

Here are the details and what I've tried:

1) uriMine, the location where the image gets stored, as it is originally returned from facebook's staging resource upload call is:
  "fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDE4NTY0NzE4MDQ0MTUwNjA6MTM5ODI2Nzc3Ng==".  I don't know what the protocol "fbstaging:" is all about (I searched and searched online but nothing) but I
ran the app as is with that at first.  The result was, well, unpredictable results apparently, as it got stuck in a loop (the looper class kept repeating in no particular pattern).  It would show the post screen but you couldn't type in a message as it would lock up, close, repeat etc...

2) After getting a little education online about well formed URL's I replaced the fbstaging:// with h..  and thus changed the uriMine variable to the following:
h..graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDE4NTY0NzE4MDQ0MTUwNjA6MTM5ODI2Nzc3Ng==
  This solved the endless loop problem (made the post work fine) except it would not show any image.

3) To see if it would work with any old normal URL of the form h..blablabla.com/image_resource I hardcoded URL's of a few images online and it worked fine, and showed the images.

4) Ok, I promise, I'm all most done (whew!).  So, where it stands right now is:

> a) passing uriMine as fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/etc etc
>     makes it freak out.
>
> b) sending a normal URL of an online resource works fine (formed as a browser forms it, by the way).
>
> c) prepending http://www.  instead of the fbstaging://  makes the post work but facebook doesn't show the image, as if it can't find it.

By the way, going directly to the above by copy/pasting it into a browser gets redirected to the following:

h..dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http%3A//www.graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDE4NTY0NzE4MDQ0MTUwNjA6MTM5ODI2Nzc3Ng%3D%3D&r=

as apparently it can't find it.

> SO:
>
> What is it about that URI that is wrong or what am I missing?  Please help.
>
> Thank you very much for your time and patience reading this.

```
public class FacebookActivity extends Activity {

// initialize the global object to enable passing of activity to facebook dialog
public GlobalClass globalObject = new GlobalClass();

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper; // for Facebook...to mimic android's activity life cycle

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set the calling activity...to pass to Face book
    globalObject.setCurrentActivity(this);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session currentSession = new Session(this);
    currentSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            // this callback should fire multiple times, be sure to get the right one i.e.  session.isOpened()
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                  // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                            Request imageRequest = Request.newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), bitmap, new Request.Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                                    String uriMine = "";
                                    JSONObject data = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                                    try {
                                        uriMine = data.getString("uri");
                                        uriMine = "http://www." + uriMine.substring(12); // strip off the "fbstaging://" from the uri
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), 
                                            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG))
                                        {
                                            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(globalObject.getCurrentActivity())
                                            .setLink("https://play.google.com/store")
                                            .setPicture(uriMine) 
                                            .setRequestCode(NativeProtocol.DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE)
                                            .setApplicationName("This is the App Name")
                                            .setName("This is the name")
                                            .setDescription("This is the description")
                                            .setCaption("This is the caption")
                                            .build();
                                            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
                                        }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(globalObject.getCurrentActivity(), "Please install the Facebook App first from Google Play.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            imageRequest.executeAsync();
                      }
                  }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The staging resource endpoint is only used for staging binary data for open graph objects or actions, and is not meant for the regular link shares. See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#newUploadStagingResourceWithImageRequest

In this case, you can either use the [PhotoShareDialogBuilder](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder/) (but then you can't add a link), or you can upload the image to your own hosting service, and use an http/https url in the setPicture method.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've decided to upload the image to another host.  I've found some code online that seems like it could do this, but it's quite complicated.  Could you by any chance point me in the right direction of some code/class that makes this a little more painless (i.e. ftp'ing logic for android that's already abstracted somewhat or ??)   Thanks so much for your time.